# How to get back Refresh button in nautilus

Tags: 11.10, nautilus

I really miss the refresh button in nautilus, which has been removed in Ubuntu 11.10. I found it very useful.
Is there a way to get it back. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to get refresh button back, but you can press ctrl+R to refresh. Hope that helps you in some way. :)

Comment: An easier way is to us F5 :D... But I want to know if there's a way to get it back.